# Need to debug ' expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token', first time c++ user

Tags: c++

i am trying c++, still student in uni, can't spot where the error comes from. Can someone give some help, please?

```
class  M() {
    static  bool m() {  
        cout << "Hello, do you want to tell me your name (y or n)";
        char answer = 0;
        int  times = 1;
        while(times < 3) {
            cin >> answer;
            switch(answer){
                case 'y' : 
                    return true;
                case 'n' : 
                    return false;
                default :  
                    cout << "I am sorry, I don't understand that.";
                    times += 1;
            }
            cout << "Your time's up.";
            return false;
        }    
    }
}

int main() {
    M::m();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on this line:

```
class M() {
```

You don't put brackets after class name definition. Change it to:

```
class M {
```

There are a few more issues with your code (semi-colon after class closing curly brackets, etc.), the working code would look like so:

```
class  M {
public:
    static bool m() {
        std::cout << "Hello, do you want to tell me your name (y or n)";
        char answer = 0;
        int  times = 1;
        while(times < 3) {
            std::cin >> answer;
            switch(answer){
                case 'y' :
                    return true;
                case 'n' :
                    return false;
                default :
                    std::cout << "I am sorry, I don't understand that.";
                    times += 1;
            }
            std::cout << "Your time's up.";
            return false;
        }
        // You need this so you won't get warnings.
        return false;
    }
}; // Don't forget this semicolon!

int main() {
    M SomeObject;
    SomeObject::m();
};
```

Comment: Right, but how to create an instance of the given class, because among other things main() complains that no instance of M is created. "cannot call member function ‘bool M::m()’ without object"

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how the syntax goes, things starting to make sense, just the std::cin/cout is that, in effect, Class::methodname? thanks for the help